# What could possibly cause ShellExecute to return SE_ERR_OOM (error 8)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, out-of-memory, shellexecute

I frequently call ShellExecute from a native C++/Win32 application to execute any shell item selected by the end-user from the GUI. Items are either executable files/scripts or links (.lnk). In some conditions that remain obscure to me, the following function sometimes returns `8` (`SE_ERR_OOM` error; only very briefly documented). As a result, the item is not executed. What could possibly cause this error?

```
int doExecute(LPCTSTR file, LPCTSTR args, LPCTSTR workDir)
{
    assert(file && *file);
    HRESULT hRes = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    assert(hRes == S_OK || hRes == S_FALSE);
    int code = (int)ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, file, args, workDir, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    doLog("ShellExecute returned: %d, %u", code, GetLastError()); // EDIT
    CoUninitialize();
    return code;
}
```

The context:

- Windows8 64bit, application is 32bit, could not try on any other machine
- Application is multi-threaded
- By design, a new thread is always created specifically to do this call
- The assertions in this code never break during my debug sessions
- The application itself does not make direct use of COM but may have to call Win32 APIs that indirectly use it since it interacts quite frequently with the shell. In these cases, COM is always initialized with the same flags than shown above.
- The flags passed to `CoInitializeEx` have been blindly chosen after MSDN recommendation (see [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) documentation), not because of a personal choice

Observations about the bug so far:

- It's rare
- It occurred only after one or several hibernations (my application is always running on my laptop and I use it quite often)
- An immediate call to [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) after calling `ShellExecute` always returned `0`
- As far as I can remember, it always happened while trying to execute a `.lnk` file, but not always the same file
- A quick look at `Process Explorer` (sysinternals.com) running on the machine does not show any peak of use of memory
- **edit**: I made a last test before posting here by calling `doExecute` 200 times in a row. All processes were spawned without error.

Comment: If you want proper error handling, use ShellExecuteEx.

Comment: "I frequently call ShellExecute".  That does stop somewhere if you don't also check what happens to the processes you start and throttle.  A process is by far the most expensive operating system object you can create.  The resource that typically poofs is the kernel's unpaged memory pool, you do get OOM when that happens.  "System out of memory", as descriptive as you can get.  Task Manager, if you can still start it, ought to show a lot of active processes.

Comment: `doExecute` does not call [`SetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680627.aspx). Calling [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) after `doExecute` returns is therefore meaningless (see Remarks section).

Comment: If you're calling `CoInitializeEx` and `CoUnitialize` more than once per thread I would try to avoid that. Most applications only call `CoInitializeEx` once per thread, and many never call `CoUnitialize`.

Comment: @HansPassant I forgot to mention that, before posting here I made a test with a loop of 200 `doExecute` calls. All the processes were spawned without any error. Thanks, I edited my post.

Comment: @RossRidge `CoInitializeEx` might indeed be called more than once per thread. But when it's the case, each call to `CoInitializeEx` is always followed by its counter part `CoUnitialize`. This behavior seems to comply with the documentation unless I missed something? It would require some modifications to my code to ensure `CoInitializeEx` is only called once per thread so I would prefer to _ensure_ it's the way to go.

Comment: @IInspectable I obviously shaved too much the code here for the sake of clarity but in the application, I do call `GetLastError` immediately after `ShellExecute`. I will edit the OP.

Comment: @polyvertex It is utterly pointless to call `GetLastError` since `ShellExecute` does not return information that way. You must read the documentation more carefully. As I said right at the top, if you want proper error handling you must use `ShellExecuteEx`. Remember that `ShellExecute` is only retained for backwards compatibility. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/10/18/10360604.aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will replace `ShellExecute` with `ShellExecuteEx` and restart my tests.

Comment: That's a good move. You are more likely to get informative error messages that way.

Comment: While the documentation says each `CoInitializeEx` should be matched with a `CoUninitialize` it only describes a scenario where these calls are nested and COM is only actually initialized and uninitialized once during the lifetime of a thread. In particular since `CoUninitialize` discards non-COM messages from the thread's message queue, which is a problem if your thread still has other messages to processes. In your case I'd be worried about COM DLLs being loaded by `ShellExecute` and then unloaded by `CoUninitialize` multiple times per thread and not handling this unusual case correctly.

Comment: @RossRidge I will investigate that way, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a long run of tests, the bug never occurred anymore after I applied some changes to the code, following advises from @DavidHeffernan and @RossRidge. While I can't really consider this as a definitive answer per se since I still don't know what happened exactly under the hood, I haven't been able to reproduce the bug so far.

Modifications applied:

- Replaced the `ShellExecute` call by `ShellExecuteEx`.
- Call `CoInitializeEx` once for all for every new thread, without its `CoUninitialize` counter-part. But kept the following nested `CoInitializeEx`-`CoUninitialize` pairs.

**Edit:** In case someone needs it, just to confirm the problem didn't occur anymore, even after several months of tests, having these modifications applied.